# setting up Tensorflowjs on Apple Silicon

Tags: node.js, tensorflow.js, node-gyp

i was hoping to find some info regarding this [here](https://old.reddit.com/r/TensorFlowJS/comments/11t32x9/error_in_installing_tensroflowjs_for_tfjsnode_in/?sort=controversial), but OP seems to have abandoned the post.  i've spent an unreasonable amount of time trying to troubleshoot this over the past few days, and anything i have found online regarding this subject has pretty much left me spinning my wheels.

i started reading [Gant Man's book](https://github.com/GantMan/learn-tfjs) for learning Tensorflow.js this weekend, and was excited to get into Chapter 2 which has the first relevant example code, and gets tfjs up and running in a local node environment.  however, these `node-gyp` and `node-pre-gyp` errors have been haunting me whenever the [tfjs-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tensorflow/tfjs-node) package is attempted to be installed and i haven't found a way around them.

here's my log including the errors i get when installing via `yarn`

```bash
yarn

yarn install v1.22.19

warning ../../../../../../../package.json: No license field

warning package-lock.json found. Your project contains lock files generated by tools other than Yarn. It is advised not to mix package managers in order to avoid resolution inconsistencies caused by unsynchronized lock files. To clear this warning, remove package-lock.json.

[1/4]   Resolving packages...

[2/4]   Fetching packages...

[3/4]   Linking dependencies...

warning "@tensorflow/tfjs-node > @tensorflow/tfjs > @tensorflow/tfjs-data@3.21.0" has unmet peer dependency "seedrandom@^3.0.5".

[4/4]   Building fresh packages...

[3/3] ⠄ @tensorflow/tfjs-node

[2/3] ⠄ nodemon

error /Users/genericusername/Desktop/WORKING FILES/repos/learn-tfjs/chapter2/node/node-example/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node: Command failed.

Exit code: 1

Command: node scripts/install.js

Arguments: 

Directory: /Users/genericusername/Desktop/WORKING FILES/repos/learn-tfjs/chapter2/node/node-example/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node

Output:

CPU-darwin-3.21.1.tar.gz

* Downloading libtensorflow

https://storage.googleapis.com/tf-builds/libtensorflow_r2_7_darwin_arm64_cpu.tar.gz

* Building TensorFlow Node.js bindings

node-pre-gyp install failed with error: Error: Command failed: node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok

node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@1.0.9

node-pre-gyp info using node@20.3.0 | darwin | arm64

node-pre-gyp info check checked for "/Users/genericusername/Desktop/WORKING FILES/repos/learn-tfjs/chapter2/node/node-example/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node/lib/napi-v8/tfjs_binding.node" (not found)

node-pre-gyp http GET https://storage.googleapis.com/tf-builds/pre-built-binary/napi-v8/3.21.1/CPU-darwin-3.21.1.tar.gz

node-pre-gyp ERR! install response status 404 Not Found on https://storage.googleapis.com/tf-builds/pre-built-binary/napi-v8/3.21.1/CPU-darwin-3.21.1.tar.gz 

node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for @tensorflow/tfjs-node@3.21.1 and node@20.3.0 (node-v115 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 

node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error response status 404 Not Found on https://storage.googleapis.com/tf-builds/pre-built-binary/napi-v8/3.21.1/CPU-darwin-3.21.1.tar.gz 

gyp info it worked if it ends with ok

gyp info using node-gyp@9.3.1

gyp info using node@20.3.0 | darwin | arm64

gyp info ok 

gyp info it worked if it ends with ok

gyp info using node-gyp@9.3.1

gyp info using node@20.3.0 | darwin | arm64

gyp info find Python using Python version 3.10.9 found at "/Users/genericusername/anaconda3/bin/python3"

gyp info spawn /Users/genericusername/anaconda3/bin/python3

gyp info spawn args [

gyp info spawn args   '/Users/genericusername/.nvm/versions/node/v20.3.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',

gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',

gyp info spawn args   '-f',

gyp info spawn args   'make',

gyp info spawn args   '-I',

gyp info spawn args   '/Users/genericusername/Desktop/WORKING FILES/repos/learn-tfjs/chapter2/node/node-example/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node/build/config.gypi',

gyp info spawn args   '-I',

gyp info spawn args   '/Users/genericusername/.nvm/versions/node/v20.3.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',

gyp info spawn args   '-I',

gyp info spawn args   '/Users/genericusername/Library/Caches/node-gyp/20.3.0/include/node/common.gypi',

gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',

gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',

gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/genericusername/Library/Caches/node-gyp/20.3.0',

gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/Users/genericusername/.nvm/versions/node/v20.3.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',

gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/genericusername/Library/Caches/node-gyp/20.3.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',

gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/genericusername/Desktop/WORKING FILES/repos/learn-tfjs/chapter2/node/node-example/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node',

gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',

gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',

gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',

gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',

gyp info spawn args   'build',

gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'

gyp info spawn args ]

gyp info ok 

gyp info it worked if it ends with ok

gyp info using node-gyp@9.3.1

gyp info using node@20.3.0 | darwin | arm64

gyp info spawn make

gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]

clang: error: no such file or directory: 'FILES/repos/learn-tfjs/chapter2/node/node-example/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node/deps/include'

make: *** [Release/obj.target/tfjs_binding/binding/tfjs_backend.o] Error 1

gyp ERR! build error 

gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2

gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/genericusername/.nvm/versions/node/v20.3.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:203:23)

gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:511:28)

gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:293:12)

gyp ERR! System Darwin 22.5.0

gyp ERR! command "/Users/genericusername/.nvm/versions/node/v20.3.0/bin/node" "/Users/genericusername/.nvm/versions/node/v20.3.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/Users/genericusername/Desktop/WORKING FILES/repos/learn-tfjs/chapter2/node/node-example/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node/lib/napi-v8/tfjs_binding.node" "--module_name=tfjs_binding" "--module_path=/Users/genericusername/Desktop/WORKING FILES/repos/learn-tfjs/chapter2/node/node-example/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node/lib/napi-v8" "--napi_version=9" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=8" "--node_napi_label=napi-v8"

gyp ERR! cwd /Users/genericusername/Desktop/WORKING FILES/repos/learn-tfjs/chapter2/node/node-example/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node

gyp ERR! node -v v20.3.0

gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.3.1

gyp ERR! not ok 

node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 

node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/Users/genericusername/.nvm/versions/node/v20.3.0/bin/node /Users/genericusername/.nvm/versions/node/v20.3.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/genericusername/Desktop/WORKING FILES/repos/learn-tfjs/chapter2/node/node-example/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node/lib/napi-v8/tfjs_binding.node --module_name=tfjs_binding --module_path=/Users/genericusername/Desktop/WORKING FILES/repos/learn-tfjs/chapter2/node/node-example/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node/lib/napi-v8 --napi_version=9 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=8 --node_napi_label=napi-v8' (1)

node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/genericusername/Desktop/WORKING FILES/repos/learn-tfjs/chapter2/node/node-example/node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:89:23)

node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:511:28)

node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1098:16)

node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:304:5)

node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 22.5.0

node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/Users/genericusername/.nvm/versions/node/v20.3.0/bin/node" "/Users/genericusername/Desktop/WORKING FILES/repos/learn-tfjs/chapter2/node/node-example/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"

node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /Users/genericusername/Desktop/WORKING FILES/repos/learn-tfjs/chapter2/node/node-example/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node

node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v20.3.0

node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v1.0.9
```

- i'm currently running Apple silicon (M2 Max) @ Ventura 13.4
- i can confirm i've got `xcode-select` installed
- `uname -m`  and `node -e 'console.log(os.arch())'` returns  `arm64`
  (per the instructions on the tfjs-node npm page)
- `python2` is @ v2.7.12 and `python` is @ v3.10.9

happy to provide any other relevant info.  thanks in advance for any responses or nudges in the right direction.

Comment: revisiting this and doing more investigation..


so this particular error line `node-pre-gyp ERR! install response status 404 Not Found on https://storage.googleapis.com/tf-builds/pre-built-binary/napi-v8/3.21.1/CPU-darwin-3.21.1.tar.gz` is sticking out so i decided to look at the directory of builds available.


as i'm observing the directory here: https://storage.googleapis.com/tf-builds/ i don't see a `CPU-darwin-3.21.1.tar.gz` build even listed.  the only darwin specific build close is `napi-v7/3.6.1/CPU-darwin-3.6.1.tar.gz`.